# Error 414 URI Too Long in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

When trying to update image from phpmyadmin, error 414 uri too long error is thrown. Now the request is made as "GET" request and that is why error is thrown. Not understanding how to solve this issue,tried many forums but not satisfied with solution's.If there are some changes to be made in php.ini or httpconfig files please guide me.
Thank's in advanced.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of phpMyAdmin you're using and which web browser? Does this occur if you try a different browser?

Comment: phpmyadmin version is 4.0.4 and browser is chrome. In mozilla firefox also same problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, version 4.0.4 is quite outdated, I suggest you upgrade to a more modern version (provided your MySQL and PHP versions are new enough; the only reason to keep phpMyAdmin 4.0.x around is if your MySQL or PHP versions are really, really old).

According to [this](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/qa_4_0/faq.html#i-have-table-with-many-100-columns-and-when-i-try-to-browse-table-i-get-series-of-errors-like-warning-unable-to-parse-url-how-can-this-be-fixed) and [that](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/qa_4_0/faq.html#in-internet-explorer-5-0-5-5-or-6-0-i-get-an-error-like-page-not-found-when-trying-to-modify-a-row-in-a-table-with-many-columns-or-with-a-text-column), you may be able to work around the issue by adding a primary or unique key to your table.